# thumbnail creation in PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a thumbnail from a bigger image. Therefore I used a script from a german tutorial found at http://www.php-resource.de/tutorials/tutorial,24,Thumbnails-mit-PHP-erzeugen,1.htm
The creation of a thumbnail from the hdd works nicely but i want to create a thumbnail from a image received by a http post request. ($inputImage = file_get_contents('php://input');)
Problem is that in the script the image is accessed from the local disk using the path.
eg. $size=getimagesize("PicPath/picName");

Can I access the image saved in the $inputImage variable?

Comment: The image will have a temporary location. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for information about the $_FILES variable that stores information on uploaded files, including the temporary filename.

Comment: alright, seams to work, but is there any other way to create a thumbnail without saving the image on the local disk?

Comment: You aren't saving the file on the disk. Apache (assuming you are using Apache) is saving it to the disk as part of the HTTP protocol of handling the Post request. Technically, it could be saved to a RAM disk, which is logically secondary storage, but physically in primary storage - but that is just a semantic argument. The Post request will get put on the disk before your PHP script ever begins.